# Oddly shaped markers in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently installed ggplot2 and tried a qplot. The plot comes out like this,
[image]

If you notice you can see that the markers seem to look deformed rather than circles. Is there a way to correct this?

Here is my code:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(1410)

qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds)
```

EDIT: The plot looks fine when exported to a pdf.

I am using R3.0.2 ggplot2_0.9.3.1 on elementary OS.Thanks.

Comment: How did you save the plot you included with your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually don't worry about the look of the picture in the "window view" / "r view" -- it is just a graphical view of what the picture will look given the current setting for the resolution.

If possible, I save a picture as an eps or pdf file. They are vector based picture and scale well regardless of size.

If I don't use an eps or pdf file, I use png files to save my pictures:

```
g1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=X1, y=Y1)+
geom_point(x)

png("high_res_png.png", width = 10000, height = 7000, res = 1300)
print(g1)
dev.off()
```

Using a lot of pixels on a png will prevent the "saved" picture from looking "fuzzy" or "oddly" shaped (the size of it will be large, but the png looks good even when you zoom in). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it was the RStudio window that was messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

The goofy looking circles is an artifact of your window system; on my Mac OS X (Quartz) setup, default qplot gives great-looking circles. However, I recall that the points do look a little like yours on my Linux box at home...

Shape is customizable, though. The following gives squares rotated 45 degrees, for instance:

```
qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds) + scale_shape_identity() + geom_point(shape = 23)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using a linux distro. Any ideas if I could correct this at the OS level?